# How to use WHERE for foreign key of a JOINed table in Doctrine?

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, associations, foreign-key-relationship, query-builder

I have a structure of three tables/entities: `User` (table `users`; columns `id` and `name`), `Room` (table `roome`; columns `id` and `number`), and `RoomUser` (`user_room`; columns `id`, `user_id`, `room_id`).

Now I want to retrieve all `Room`s for a `User` with a given `id`. **How to do this without to join `Room`s?**

```
$userId = 123;
// ...
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder->select('r')
    ->from(Room::class, 'r')
    ->join('r.RoomUsers', 'ru')
    ->where('ru.room_id = :userId') // room_id? ru.Room.id?
    ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
    ->getQuery();

$rooms = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

So in SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms
JOIN room_users ON room_users.room_id = rooms.id
WHERE user_id = 123;
```

How to implement this simple request with the `QueryBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MEMBER OF` ([docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)) for that:

```
$query = $queryBuilder->select('r')
    ->from(Room::class, 'r')
    ->where(':user_id MEMBER OF r.users')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $userId)
```